# Can liftM differ from liftA?

Tags: haskell, theory, typeclass, category-theory

According to [the Typeclassopedia](http://www.haskell.org/wikiupload/8/85/TMR-Issue13.pdf) (among other sources), `Applicative` logically belongs between `Monad` and `Pointed` (and thus `Functor`) in the type class hierarchy, so we would ideally have something like this if the Haskell prelude were written today:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

class Functor f => Pointed f where
    pure :: a -> f a

class Pointed f => Applicative f where
    (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

class Applicative m => Monad m where
    -- either the traditional bind operation
    (>>=) :: (m a) -> (a -> m b) -> m b
    -- or the join operation, which together with fmap is enough
    join :: m (m a) -> m a
    -- or both with mutual default definitions
    f >>= x = join ((fmap f) x)
    join x = x >>= id
    -- with return replaced by the inherited pure
    -- ignoring fail for the purposes of discussion
```

(Where those default definitions were re-typed by me from the [explanation at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_%28functional_programming%29#fmap_and_join), errors being my own, but if there are errors it is at least in principle possible.)

As the libraries are currently defined, we have:

```
liftA :: (Applicative f) => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
liftM ::       (Monad m) => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

and:

```
(<*>) :: (Applicative f) => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
ap    ::       (Monad m) => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
```

Note the similarity between these types within each pair.

My question is: are `liftM` (as distinct from `liftA`) and `ap` (as distinct from `<*>`), simply a result of the historical reality that `Monad` wasn't designed with `Pointed` and `Applicative` in mind? Or are they in some other behavioral way (potentially, for some legal `Monad` definitions) distinct from the versions that only require an `Applicative` context?

If they are distinct, could you provide a simple set of definitions (obeying the laws required of `Monad`, `Applicative`, `Pointed`, and `Functor` definitions described in the Typeclassopedia and elsewhere but not enforced by the type system) for which `liftA` and `liftM` behave differently?

Alternatively, if they are not distinct, could you prove their equivalence using those same laws as premises?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`liftA`, `liftM`, `fmap`, and `.` *should* all be the same function, and they *must* be if they satisfy the functor law:

```
fmap id = id
```

However, this is not checked by Haskell.

Now for Applicative. It's possible for `ap` and `<*>` to be distinct for some functors simply because there could be more than one implementation that satisfies the types and the laws. For example, List has more than one possible `Applicative` instance. You could declare an applicative as follows:

```
instance Applicative [] where
  (f:fs) <*> (x:xs) = f x : fs <*> xs
  _      <*> _      = []
  pure              = repeat
```

The `ap` function would still be defined as `liftM2 id`, which is the `Applicative` instance that comes for free with every `Monad`. But here you have an example of a type constructor having more than one `Applicative` instance, both of which satisfy the laws. But if your monads and your applicative functors disagree, it's considered good form to have different types for them. For example, the `Applicative` instance above does not agree with the monad for `[]`, so you should really say `newtype ZipList a = ZipList [a]` and then make the new instance for `ZipList` instead of `[]`.

Comment: OK, that's true, there is more than one Applicative instance and more than one Monad instance for some types. But, under the definitions above the pure/return implementation would have to be shared between the Applicative instance and the Monad instance. Does this mean that, to satisfy the laws, that <*> and ap would have to be the same? It looks like your example relies on making an Applicative instance for [] with pure = repeat, but still using the Prelude Monad instance for [] with return = ([])?

Comment: I may be missing something, but it is not true that a function of type `forall a,b. (a -> b) -> F a -> F b` is guaranteed to be `fmap`. For example, consider `notmap f xs = zipWith ($) (repeat (const . f $ head xs)) xs`.

Comment: @Apocalisp: given just the type of fmap, you can still have exotic members. The side condition fmap id = id is enough to force the issue though, and I think the extra quantifier you put in over 'f' is cheating. ;) Doug, while the definition of Functor is unique given the laws the Applicative laws are loose enough to permit multiple compliant definitions. However, by convention, the Monad and Applicative for a given type should be made compatible.

Comment: Why is `.` mentioned in the first paragraph? `.` is a specific instance of `fmap` (or of the other two), it simply can't be equal to e.g. `liftM` applied in the context of the `IO` monad, right?

Answer (score 10):

They *can* differ, but they *shouldn't*.

They can differ because they can have different implementations: one is defined in an `instance Applicative` while the other is defined in an `instance Monad`. But if they indeed differ, then I'd say the programmer who wrote those instances wrote misleading code.

You are right: the functions exist as they do for historical reasons. People have strong ideas about how things should have been.