# FRP (reactive): How to use filterE?

Tags: haskell, frp

I expect the next will print "()" 10 times in a second. But it hangs after a second. Why?

```
adaptE $ fmap print $ filterE (const True) $ atTimes [0.1, 0.2 ..]
```

I found that it is related to liftM used in filterE:

```
filterE :: (Ord t, Bounded t) => (a -> Bool) -> EventG t a -> EventG t a
filterE p m = justE (liftM f m)
 where
   f a | p a        = Just a
       | otherwise  = Nothing
```

I tried to reimplement `filterE` using `fmap` and it seems to work. Why?
How the standard `filterE` is designed to be used?

I found myself reimplementing a lot of standard functions provided by the `reactive` package (e.g. `diffE`, `integrate`). Does it mean that the package is buggy or I use it in a wrong way?

Thanks!

Comment: [fmap, <$>, liftA, liftM are the same](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634911/can-liftm-differ-from-lifta/1635208#1635208).

Comment: They SHOULD be the same. But `adaptE . fmap print $ atTimes [0.1, 0.2 .. 10]` works 10 sec and `adaptE . liftM print $ atTimes [0.1, 0.2 .. 10]` never returns. Why?

Comment: reactive is pretty buggy

Comment: @luqui, seems you answer in the only acceptable) Could you please make it a real answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience reactive is buggy, especially with regard to the `Monad` instance of `Event`  (the monad `join` operation is slightly too strict and we're not exactly sure why).  Avoid that if possible.  Reactive was an experiment, and represents what might be possible with more runtime support.  See Yampa for a more stable, reliable, and well-traveled FRP library, even if it is a bit less expressive.