# Haskell: type mismatch when chaining getPermissions and searchable?

Tags: haskell

I'm a bit of a newbie with haskell and am trying to understand why the following code seems to fail.

Why can I not write:

```
getPermissions "." >>= searchable
```

but I can write:

```
do { p <- getPermissions "."; return $ searchable p }
```

The former fails with the following error:

```
<interactive>:65:24:
    Couldn't match type `Bool' with `IO b0'
    Expected type: Permissions -> IO b0
    Actual type: Permissions -> Bool
    In the second argument of `(>>=)', namely `searchable'
    In the expression: getPermissions "." >>= searchable
    In an equation for `it': it = getPermissions "." >>= searchable
```

My understanding is that `(>>=)` operates similarly to `(<-)` effectively passing the unwrapped value in the monad to a non-monad function.

What am I not understanding correctly? And how could one chain/compose `getPermissions` and `searchable` together concisely?

Many thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: your second example is equivalent to:getPermissions "." >>= (return . searchable)

Comment: Thanks, @Arjan. I was just noticing that I could use `getPermissions "." >>= (\p -> return $ searchable p)` which seems to be the same as your comment. But I'm still unclear on why this example seems different from other IO examples I've seen and tried before. Do some non-monad function return types promote to monad return types easier than others?

Comment: Strike my last question about type promotion... I think I've just been overlooking or ignoring the return type of functions on the rhs of the bind. So much type info to keep in mind...

Comment: I just want to add that the parentheses in Arjan's comment are not necessary, and that you can also write `searchable <$> getPermissions "."` where `<$>` is the infix synonym for `fmap`, defined in `Control.Applicative`.

Comment: Thanks, @raymonad! That's a great example of using `<$>` in practice. I'll keep a note of it for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Arjan's comment above helped me get a better sense of what's going on. And some additional exploration on my part seemed to solidify the solution.

As mentioned in my second comment above, I seem to have overlooked the return type of the function used in the rhs of the bind (`>>=`). Since `searchable` returns a `Bool`, it doesn't fully qualify as the rhs' type which needs to be some type wrapped in `IO`, per the error message I saw above (`IO b0`). By promoting `searchable`'s `Bool` return type using `return` I satisfy `>>=`'s rhs type.

@Arjan's code in his comment also gives a concise form I was looking for:

```
getPermissions "." >>= (return . searchable)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: `Control.Monad.liftM` is the library function to do this. The applicative functions in the other answer are even better, though. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634911/can-liftm-differ-from-lifta. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Control-Monad.html#liftM